# Api Documentation and Enum Semantics

Tags: c#, api, enums, documentation

I am creating API documentation for my REST web services.  The requests and responses contain some enums, but what is a good section title to describe these.  The title "Enumerations" sound to programmy, am I wrong?

```
Gender

Male - 1
Female - 2

Pool Team Status

All - 1
Active - 2
Active and Paid - 3

Registration Status

All - 1
Active - 2
Active and Paid - 3

Status

All - 1
Active - 2
Active and Paid - 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to them as Options, Alternatives or any other synonym (in case that is what they are).

Nevertheless, assuming you are writing the documentation for other programmers and not just as something that management has to go through, I think Enumerations or Enums is good, as it will be clear to your audience, which is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Personally, I've seen: type, mode, style, option, and flags.  Knowing the context would be beneficial, as enums can represent many different things.

Comment: I thought about flags, type might make sense.

Comment: I would use something like: 
"the following options/filters can be used to specify the Pool Team Status:
- All: ... -Active:... -Active and Paid:..." where ... should be replaced by the description of each option/filter.